# Sequence of continued powers defined recursively

Tags: calculus, analysis

I have a series ${a_n}$ defined recursively by $a_1 = b$ and $a_{n+1} = b^{a_n}$, with $b \ge 1$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z} $.  I am trying to show that ${a_n}$ is bounded above if $1 \le b < 3^{1/3}$, and that if $1 \le b <3^{1/3}$ then $a_n$ converges to a value A which satisfies $A=b^A$.  I have had no luck so far.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, just to get me started on the right track.

Comment: Your upper bound can be improved to $e^{1/e}$. What do you know about fixed point iterations? Are you aware of conditions of convergence?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem applied to $f(x) = b^x$?

Comment: I have tried to get this to work, but I don't know if it does.  For example, $1.4 < 3^{1/3} < e^{1/e}$, but taking $x=32,y=2$ for example, we have that $d(f(x),f(y))>47000$, but obviously $32-2=30$, so $d(f(x),f(y)) \nleq d(x,y)$

Answer (score 1):

This operation of *repeated exponentiation* is called [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration), and its [convergence for infinite heights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_infinite_heights) has already been studied and solved by Euler three centuries ago. It relies on noticing that $y=x^y$, where $y(x)$ represents infinite tetration. Then, by taking its logarithm, we have $x=\exp\bigg(\dfrac{\ln y}y\bigg)$, whose maximum is $x=\sqrt[e]e$ in $y=e$, as can be seen from computing the roots of its derivative. So *y* diverges to infinity for $x>\sqrt[e]e$. It also diverges through oscillation for $x<\dfrac1{e^e}$. This comes from the fact that infinite tetration can also be expressed as $y=x^{x^y}$, which has two alternating states.